# Spring MVC test: Model is always null after posting

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I'm having an headache with this problem. I want to simulate form post of data in my test, but user model is always null and thus always invalid. Here is the controller action code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addUser(ModelMap map, @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user, BindingResult result,
        HttpServletResponse response, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
    if(!result.hasErrors()) {
        try {
            String userStatus = user.getId() != null ? "User Updated: " : "User Created: ";

            userService.saveOrUpdateUser(user);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("userStatusMessage", userStatus + user.toString());

            return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/users"));
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage());

            return null;
        }
    }

    map.addAttribute("genders", generateGenders());

    return new ModelAndView("addUser", "user", user);
}
```

And this is the test code:

```
@Test
public void createUserTest() throws Exception {
    User user = generateSampleUser(null, "Pera", "Peric");

    when(userServiceMock.saveOrUpdateUser(user)).thenAnswer(resolveUserIdGeneration(user)).thenReturn(user);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/users/add")
            .param("firstName", user.getFirstName())
            .param("email", user.getEmail())
            .param("birthday", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(user.getBirthday()))
            .param("gender", user.getGender().toString())
            .param("personalNumber", user.getPersonalNumber()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(model().attributeHasNoErrors("user"));

    verify(userServiceMock, times(1)).saveOrUpdateUser(user);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(userServiceMock);
}
```

And finally model code:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "BADMINTON_USER")
public class User extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @Column(length = 64, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 3, max = 64)
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 64, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 3, max = 64)
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @NotNull
    private Date birthday;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @NotNull
    private Gender gender;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 13)
    @Size(min = 13, max = 13, message = "Personal number must be exactly 13 characters long.")
    @NotNull
    private String personalNumber;

    @Column(length = 64, nullable = false)
    @Email
    @Size(min = 10, max = 64)
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @Column(length = 20, nullable = true)
    @Phone
    private String phone1;

    @Column(length = 20, nullable = true)
    @Phone
    private String phone2;

    @Column(length = 200, nullable = true)
    private String note;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Slot> slots = new ArrayList<Slot>();

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getPersonalNumber() {
        return personalNumber;
    }

    public void setPersonalNumber(String personalNumber) {
        this.personalNumber = personalNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone1() {
        return phone1;
    }

    public void setPhone1(String phone1) {
        this.phone1 = phone1;
    }

    public String getPhone2() {
        return phone2;
    }

    public void setPhone2(String phone2) {
        this.phone2 = phone2;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public List<Slot> getSlots() {
        return slots;
    }

    public void setSlots(List<Slot> slots) {
        this.slots = slots;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d, %s %s, %s, %s, %s, %s", this.getId(), this.getFirstName(), this.getLastName(),
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(this.getBirthday()), this.getGender().getDisplayName(), this.getPersonalNumber(),
                this.getEmail());
    }
}
```

Edit: The trace log can be found here: http://pastebin.com/KyRjujyV

Comment: I think that if you specify model name, then it should be a path prefix (i.e. params should be `user.firstName`, ...). With a single model object being processed you can omit the name (use `@ModelAttribute` without a name specified).

Comment: Sorry, but that does not do the trick. It's still telling me that user is null.

Comment: Just to clarify - you are getting NPE at `user.getId()`?

Comment: If you think on NullPointerException than no. Maybe I can post stack trace for you to see it?

Comment: Try to have different Model object, do not have Hibernate's entity object ...

Comment: Why? Entity object is just simple POJO. There is no need to create separate object.

Comment: That is not a good practice

Comment: Adding the object of the other name and same structure is stupid and definitely not a good practice.

Comment: Who is writing `user: may not be null`? Where does this message come from?

Comment: I configured the Log4j for tracing.

Comment: But this is not a log message. This looks like `System.out.println`.

Comment: Log4j is configured to track and write application events to the console.